# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "play" is not found

Tags: python, discord

I am having troubles gettimg my commands to work, it keeps telling me that they do not exist when they clearly do. I've been stumped on this for hours and can't figure out why its not working. I've tried doing commands.command() instead of @commands.command(), but no luck, i tried explicitly defining the name of the command @commands.command(name="play") but still no luck

```
import youtube_dl
import pafy
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user.name} is ready.")

bot.run("....")


class Player(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot 
        self.song_queue = {}

        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        for guild in self.bot.guilds:
            self.song_queue[guild.id] = []

    async def check_queue(self, ctx):
        if len(self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id]) > 0:
            await self.play_song(ctx, self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id][0])
            self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id].pop(0)

    async def search_song(self, amount, song, get_url=False):
        info = await self.bot.loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({"format" : "bestaudio", "quiet" : True}).extract_info(f"ytsearch{amount}:{song}", download=False, ie_key="YoutubeSearch"))
        if len(info["entries"]) == 0: return None

        return [entry["webpage_url"] for entry in info["entries"]] if get_url else info

    async def play_song(self, ctx, song):
        url = pafy.new(song).getbestaudio().url
        ctx.voice_client.play(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url)), after=lambda error: self.bot.loop.create_task(self.check_queue(ctx)))
        ctx.voice_client.source.volume = 0.5

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            return await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel, please connect to the channel you want the bot to join.")

        if ctx.voice_client is not None:
            await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

        await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()

    @commands.command()
    async def leave(self, ctx):
        if ctx.voice_client is not None:
            return await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

        await ctx.send("I am not connected to a voice channel.")

    @commands.command(name="play")
    async def play(self, ctx, *, song=None):
        if song is None:
            return await ctx.send("You must include a song to play.")

        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            return await ctx.send("I must be in a voice channel to play a song.")

        # handle song where song isn't url
        if not ("youtube.com/watch?" in song or "https://youtu.be/" in song):
            await ctx.send("Searching for song, this may take a few seconds.")

            result = await self.search_song(1, song, get_url=True)

            if result is None:
                return await ctx.send("Sorry, I could not find the given song, try using my search command.")

            song = result[0]

        if ctx.voice_client.source is not None:
            queue_len = len(self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id])

            if queue_len < 10:
                self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id].append(song)
                return await ctx.send(f"I am currently playing a song, this song has been added to the queue at position: {queue_len+1}.")

            else:
                return await ctx.send("Sorry, I can only queue up to 10 songs, please wait for the current song to finish.")

        await self.play_song(ctx, song)
        await ctx.send(f"Now playing: {song}")

    @commands.command()
    async def search(self, ctx, *, song=None):
        if song is None: return await ctx.send("You forgot to include a song to search for.")

        await ctx.send("Searching for song, this may take a few seconds.")

        info = await self.search_song(5, song)

        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Results for '{song}':", description="*You can use these URL's to play an exact song if the one you want isn't the first result.*\n", colour=discord.Colour.red())
        
        amount = 0
        for entry in info["entries"]:
            embed.description += f"[{entry['title']}]({entry['webpage_url']})\n"
            amount += 1

        embed.set_footer(text=f"Displaying the first {amount} results.")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.command()
    async def queue(self, ctx): # display the current guilds queue
        if len(self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id]) == 0:
            return await ctx.send("There are currently no songs in the queue.")

        embed = discord.Embed(title="Song Queue", description="", colour=discord.Colour.dark_gold())
        i = 1
        for url in self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id]:
            embed.description += f"{i}) {url}\n"

            i += 1

        embed.set_footer(text="Thanks for using me!")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.command()
    async def skip(self, ctx):
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            return await ctx.send("I am not playing any song.")

        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            return await ctx.send("You are not connected to any voice channel.")

        if ctx.author.voice.channel.id != ctx.voice_client.channel.id:
            return await ctx.send("I am not currently playing any songs for you.")

        poll = discord.Embed(title=f"Vote to Skip Song by - {ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}", description="**80% of the voice channel must vote to skip for it to pass.**", colour=discord.Colour.blue())
        poll.add_field(name="Skip", value=":white_check_mark:")
        poll.add_field(name="Stay", value=":no_entry_sign:")
        poll.set_footer(text="Voting ends in 15 seconds.")

        poll_msg = await ctx.send(embed=poll) # only returns temporary message, we need to get the cached message to get the reactions
        poll_id = poll_msg.id

        await poll_msg.add_reaction(u"\u2705") # yes
        await poll_msg.add_reaction(u"\U0001F6AB") # no
        
        await asyncio.sleep(15) # 15 seconds to vote

        poll_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(poll_id)
        
        votes = {u"\u2705": 0, u"\U0001F6AB": 0}
        reacted = []

        for reaction in poll_msg.reactions:
            if reaction.emoji in [u"\u2705", u"\U0001F6AB"]:
                async for user in reaction.users():
                    if user.voice.channel.id == ctx.voice_client.channel.id and user.id not in reacted and not user.bot:
                        votes[reaction.emoji] += 1

                        reacted.append(user.id)

        skip = False

        if votes[u"\u2705"] > 0:
            if votes[u"\U0001F6AB"] == 0 or votes[u"\u2705"] / (votes[u"\u2705"] + votes[u"\U0001F6AB"]) > 0.79: # 80% or higher
                skip = True
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Skip Successful", description="***Voting to skip the current song was succesful, skipping now.***", colour=discord.Colour.green())

        if not skip:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Skip Failed", description="*Voting to skip the current song has failed.*\n\n**Voting failed, the vote requires at least 80% of the members to skip.**", colour=discord.Colour.red())

        embed.set_footer(text="Voting has ended.")

        await poll_msg.clear_reactions()
        await poll_msg.edit(embed=embed)

        if skip:
            ctx.voice_client.stop()


    @commands.command()
    async def pause(self, ctx):
        if ctx.voice_client.is_paused():
            return await ctx.send("I am already paused.")

        ctx.voice_client.pause()
        await ctx.send("The current song has been paused.")

    @commands.command()
    async def resume(self, ctx):
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            return await ctx.send("I am not connected to a voice channel.")

        if not ctx.voice_client.is_paused():
            return await ctx.send("I am already playing a song.")
        
        ctx.voice_client.resume()
        await ctx.send("The current song has been resumed.")

async def setup():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    bot.add_cog(Player(bot))

bot.loop.create_task(setup())
```

Comment: Did you try to put your command out of the cog ?

Comment: No i havent can you eloaborate on what you mean by that? @imperosol

Comment: Maybe your Cog isn't registered properly.

Comment: how would i go about registering it properly if thats the case?

Comment: you should run `setup()` before `run()`

Comment: like this? 
async def setup():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    bot.add_cog(Player(bot))   

bot.run("...")

Comment: `run()` has to be last command - it starts bot and it runs until you stop bot - and all code  which you have after `run()` is executed after you stop bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try replacing :

```
async def setup():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    bot.add_cog(Player(bot))

bot.loop.create_task(setup())
```

With just :

```
bot.add_cog(Player(bot))
```

Moreover, put you `run` statement after all setup operations, so you have :

```
# Cog declaration
bot.add_cog(Player(bot))
bot.run('....')
```

Comment: Thank you very much you solved me issue, i however am receveing a new error but that isn the point lol, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`run()` should be executed as last function because it starts bot and it runs until you stop bot.
And all code which you have after `run()` is executed after you stop bot.

```
bot.loop.create_task(setup())

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@commands.command()
```

Write this down where you wrote it down.

```
@bot.command()
```

Because:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```

Since you have assigned a "bot" variable here, the name of the variable is added first, and then the "command" is added.